# Can't enable managed push as this depends on GCM, which is not available on this device

Tags: java, sinch

I have one phone on Android 4.4.4, when I start the sinch client I get:

```
Can't enable managed push as this depends on GCM, which is not available on this device.
```

from the `mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);`. It works on another Android which is a Android on 6.0.1. Do anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: check out this, seems to be a problem with 4.4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952037/google-cloud-messaging-not-working-in-android-4-4

Comment: did u get answer, i have same issue

Comment: You need to check if the google play store is up to date or not: https://gist.github.com/skeie/04ff8b8aea5aa575ca09e48b6cb408bb

Answer (score 0):

Please update your SDK to the latest version. I had similar issue with older SDK version. It is resolved with newer one.

You can download latest SDK from here

https://www.sinch.com/downloads/

And download "VOICE & INSTANT MESSAGE SDK W/ VIDEO BETA" with version "Android SDK 3.9.7"

Comment: I have downloaded the latest SDK yesterday and my android version is 5. I have the same problem. Any more help?

Comment: Check if google play services are up to date and you have setup google account in your phone.